# Is there a way to detect whether the apk is stored on SD-card or not?

Tags: android

Is there a way to detect whether the apk is stored on SD-card or not?
How?

Comment: +1 for the question. but wonder y do u need Whether app is installed in sdcard or phone?

Comment: No, I need to detect whether app is installed or not(on SD-card only)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004650/android-2-2-how-do-i-detect-if-i-am-installed-on-the-sdcard-or-not

except inasmuch as the latter answer pertains only to API level 8 and up.  The linked page suggests using the FLAG_EXTERNAL_STORAGE flag, which is for the specific purpose desired.  This flag became available in API level 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use getApplicationInfo().sourceDir

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html

Answer (score 2):

To make the accepted answer more concrete, here's an example of how I've used it in the context of accessing files written to internal vs external storage, according to [API level 7](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles) guidelines or lower:

```
{   //...
    mInternalApp = context.getApplicationInfo().sourceDir.matches("^/data/app/.*");
    mPathInternal = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/files/";
    mPathExternal = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/"
                + PACKAGE_NAME + "/files/";
}

private File getMyFile() {
    return (mInternalApp) ? new File(mPathInternal + INT_FILE_NAME) :
                            new File(mPathExternal + EXT_FILE_NAME);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes... You can detect the same...

The apps downloaded from Android Market are stored in **/data/app** (not in SD card).
The default system applications are stored in **/system/app**

However, rooted phones can store the applications in **/sdcard/backups/apps**

Comment: There is a somewhat recent flag apps can set in their manifest if they prefer to be installed on the SD card...

Comment: Every app from the market gets installed on the phone memory by default. There is no way to move it to the SD card without rooting the device.  **Apps2SD** helps move the apps from internal memory to SD card on rooted devices only. And as mentioned above, getApplicationInfo().sourceDir can be used to detect the location.

Answer (score 0):

```
     File f = new file(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"your apk name");
     sytem,out.println(""+f.exsits);
```