# How to find out if an App has been moved to SD card on Android

Tags: android, manifest

I used the installLocation that allows figuring out if an app can be moved or not. But I cannot figure out what happens when we want to find out if an App has been moved to a SD card.

The `ApplicationInfo` attribute `FLAG_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` only tells you if the app is installed to the SD not if it has been moved to. I am generating a list of apps that could be moved to SD card. So first list I generate is using the `installLocation` of manifest. From this list I got to filter out apps which already have been moved to SD Card.

Answer (score 3):

To Check application is installed in SD Card or not, just do this:

```
ApplicationInfo io = context.getApplicationInfo();

if(io.sourceDir.startsWith("/data/")) {

//application is installed in internal memory

} else if(io.sourceDir.startsWith("/mnt/") || io.sourceDir.startsWith("/sdcard/")) {

//application is installed in sdcard(external memory)

}
```

Comment: Would be nice if those paths would be documented somewhere. I have a feeling those might be SDK dependend, or not? 
Instead of .startsWith("/sdcard/") Google recommends to use :  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()

Answer (score 1):

Is suppose [this question (and its accepted answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712185/is-there-a-way-to-detect-whether-the-apk-is-stored-on-sd-card-or-not) could help.

In short: getApplicationInfo().sourceDir, as [documented here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html).

Answer (score -1):

If your install location is auto you can either move the application from sd card to phone or vice versa. you can check the app location manually in the device application manager.

Comment: Thanks but I am writing an App so I need to find out programmatically. I need to know what Android classes could be used that would tell if an App has been moved to SD card not installed on SD card.